# Using azure app service application setting variables in reactjs typescript app returning undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service with Node.js runtime stack serving a ReactJs Typescript application. I have some API URLS in the application setting. I have tried to access them in ReactJs components using process.env.REACT_APP_URL however it returns me undefined. I have defined the application setting as seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGmU6.png)

[image]

I have a similar separate application with same Node.js runtime stack just for the Backend APIS. I have dome the same in that using process.env to access the application settings and it works in that app. But in the ReactJs Typescripts its says undefined. Please let me know how the application setting environmental variables can be used in app service for ReactJs served through Node.JS.

Answer (score 0):

I test a react app, only could get the `NODE_ENV` environment variable, any other variable could not be accessed. Have tried `envname` or `REACT_APP_envname`, both of them failed.

So in my solution, I crate the `.env.development.local` and `.env.production.local` file under the root of my project. For local test it will take `.env.development.local` environment and when run `npm run build` it will take `.env.production.local` environment.

In the `.env.production.local` I set the value `REACT_APP_testkey=testvaluedevelop` and use `process.env.REACT_APP_testkey` to read the value, then run `npm run build` then publish to azure.

[image]

Comment: Hi @George but due to the security concerns I dont want to commit and have .env file in my source control with the variables. Therefore I would like to fetch them from app settings.